# Python pack to PHP pack

Tags: php, python, struct, pack, unpack

I am trying convert a Python script to PHP. However I am having trouble getting the format right.

**Python:**

```py
print(hashlib.sha1(struct.pack('L', 1)).hexdigest())
```

Output:

```
3da89ee273be13437e7ecf760f3fbd4dc0e8d1fe
```

**PHP:**

```php
echo sha1(pack('L', 1));
```

Output:

```
3c585604e87f855973731fea83e21fab9392d2fc
```

Can someone please point me in right direction to get the same output in both languages?

Comment: The right direction is to convert PHP to Python. I KID OF COURSE!

Answer (score 3):

The differences occurs because of different integer sizes. While `L` in the php version of pack() uses hardcoded 32bit integers, Python by default uses the machine integer size. If you are working on a 64bit system you'll notice the difference. (As shown in the question)

You need to use the `=` in python to standardize the aligment **and** the size:

```
print(hashlib.sha1(struct.pack('=L', 1)).hexdigest())
```

Output:

```
3c585604e87f855973731fea83e21fab9392d2fc
```

Please refer to this docs:

- Python struct: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html
- PHP pack: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a 32 vs 64-bit issue. Are you running a 64-bit version of Python?

Note that according to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html), `L` is an "unsigned long". Since you're not specifying a [*byte order, size and alignment*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) character, Python will default to *native*. On Linux, that means 8 bytes on 64-bit, and 4 bytes on 32-bit.

It's always best to tell Python exactly what you mean when working with binary data:

- `<` for little-endian, standard size, or
- `>` for big-endian, standard size.

This will eliminate any differences, depending on what type of machine you're running on.

This example shows that you're probably using a 64-bit build of python, as `L` == `Q` (64-bit).

```
>>> print(hashlib.sha1(struct.pack('<I', 1)).hexdigest())
3c585604e87f855973731fea83e21fab9392d2fc

>>> print(hashlib.sha1(struct.pack('<Q', 1)).hexdigest())
3da89ee273be13437e7ecf760f3fbd4dc0e8d1fe
```